# Define more than one type of query GraphQL Schema - Best approach to define different types on query one one object

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Is this possible to specify more than one type of query in one schema?

```
type Query {
    productsByRegion(match : String) : [Product]
    productsByType(match : String) : [Product]
}

type Product {
    id: ID
    name: String
}
```

Expected queries which can be fired using single schema definition:

```
{
    productsByRegion {
        id
        name
    }
}

{
    productsByType {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by one query type? are you referring multiple response types? If so, you can do it using union types. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/

Comment: Add sample queries in question which can be fired. Will this be supported using union ?

Comment: Looks like graphql cache issue. Worked after server restart.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL java implementation cached some data. After server, restart both the query works fine.